# Convert an array in string format to javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have an array which is in string format,

```
var str = { 
    id: 123,
    changes: "[[atr:test1, old:null, new:null], [atr:messageText, old:test here, new:hello test], [atr:status, old:null, new:1]]"
}
var d = str.changes
```

I tried to convert the 'changes' array from string format using different methods by combining `split()`, `replace()`, `slice()` etc...and even `JSON.parse()`, but nothing worked.

Is there any way to convert this into javascript array?

Comment: This "string format" array is JSON. So think of the problem as converting JSON to an object.  Research JSON in the MSN javascript documentation and look for `parse` and `stringify` methods.

Comment: i think the literal in `changes` is not in valid JSON array syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the string is not valid anything but string. 
It is not a valid array, and the string is not valid JSON.

If you can, get the server to change it to the valid JSON string

```
"[{\"atr\":\"test1\", \"old\":null, \"new\":null}, {\"atr\":\"messageText\", \"old\":\"test here\", \"new\":\"hello test\"}, {\"atr\":\"status\", \"old\":null, \"new\":1}]"
```

If the response is ALWAYS on the format you gave, then you can create valid JSON

```js
var str = {
  id: 123,
  changes: "[[atr:test1, old:null, new:null], [atr:messageText, old:test here, new:hello test], [atr:status, old:null, new:1]]"
}

// change the inner [ ] to { }
let changes = str.changes.replace(/\[\[/g, "[{").replace(/\], \[/g, "},{").replace(/\]\]/g, "}]")

// change the unquoted keys and values to quoted keys and values
changes = changes.replace(/(\w+):/g, '"$1":').replace(/:([\w ]+)([},])/g, ':"$1"$2')

// parse the object
changes = JSON.parse(changes);

// replace "null" with null - could have been done above bt the regex would be nasty
changes.forEach(item => Object.keys(item).forEach(key => item[key] = item[key] === "null" ? null : item[key]))

console.log(changes)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the key 'changes' do not any valid JSON. You can validate, format it [here](https://jsonformatter.org/).

If there is a valid JSON in 'changes' key, It can be converted to Js array using JSON.parse();, Something like:

```
    var str = { id: 123,
            changes: `[
  [
    {
      "atr": "test1",
      "old": null,
      "new": null
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "atr": "messageText",
      "old": "test here",
      "new": "hello test"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "atr": "status",
      "old": null,
      "new": 1
    }
  ]
]`
          }
var d = JSON.parse(str.changes);

    console.log(d);

//str.changes Object:
[[[object Object] {
  atr: "test1",
  new: null,
  old: null
}], [[object Object] {
  atr: "messageText",
  new: "hello test",
  old: "test here"
}], [[object Object] {
  atr: "status",
  new: 1,
  old: null
}]]
```